# Doctrine 2 OneToOne, load owning side only when neccessary

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two entities - User and UserSettings. In User entity, I want to have UserSettings as an attribute. That would be OK, I would add a OneToOne relation but there's a problem - because UserSettings is an owning side of the relation, every time I load User entity, Doctrine has to load the UserSettings entity too.

Is there a way how to load User but not UserSettings?

I made maybe a weird solution - there's no relation between these entities and the settings are loaded by method of Facade. For example:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string")
   */
  private $name;

  /** @var UserSettings */
  private $settings;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->settings = new UserSettings();
  }


  public function setSettings(UserSettings $settings)
  {
    $this->settings = $settings;
  }

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserSettings
{

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
   */
  private $userId;

}

class UserFacade
{

  /**
   * @var EntityManager
   */
  private $em;   // is injected automatically by DI

  public function loadSettings(User $user)
  {
    $settings = $this->em->getRepository("UserSettings")->findOneBy(array("userId" => $user->id));
    $user->setSettings($settings);
  }

}

$user = $em->find("User", 1);

// if I want user's settings
$userFacade->loadSettings($user);  // now I can use  $user->getSettings()->something;
```

*Side note: UserFacade is a service class that manipulates with users' data like adding new user, editing, deleting etc. In my MVC application, controller classes communicate with Facades, not with EntityManager directly.*

That's OK - settings are loaded only when I want to. However, there are two possible problems:

a) I don't think this is a clear way

b) When I want a list of users, I cannot JOIN a table where settings are, because entities are not associated, so I have to make an extra SQL for each user.

My question is - how to solve the problem with OneToOne relation? I don't have much experience with Doctrine, so it may be a stupid question - sorry for that.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you require not to load `UserSettings` in relation? Did you profile? How much performance do you gain by not loading it?

Comment: Well, I'm creating a tiny web application on localhost just for study purposes, my database has only few records so there's no losing of performance.
I do not require but when UserSettings is not used, is it really neccessary to load it?